# Need query to determine number of attachments for each issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, inner-join, outer-join

I have a database in SQL Server that has three tables: Issues, Attachments, and Requestors. I need a single query that returns all the columns contained in the "Issues" and "Attachments" tables. Listed below is the query that I've created, but it's not working as expected:

```
SELECT A.*, 
       B.*, 
       SubQuery.attachmentcount 
FROM   [DB].[dbo].[issues] AS A 
       FULL OUTER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[requestors] AS B 
                    ON A.issue_id = B.issue_id, 
       (SELECT Count(attachments.attachment_id) AS AttachmentCount 
        FROM   issues 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN attachments 
                            ON issues.issue_id = attachments.issue_id 
        WHERE  attachments.attachment_status = 1 
        GROUP  BY issues.issue_id) AS SubQuery;
```

Pictures describing the three tables are listed below:
[image: Attachments Tbl]
[image][image]

Any ideas on how to fix my query?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need a single query that returns all the columns contained in the "Issues" and "Attachments" tables". 
Based on this sentence try this:

```
SELECT A.Issue_ID, I.Issue_Name,r.Name, COUNT(A.attachment_id) AS Count 
FROM Attachments as A 
INNER JOIN Issues I  on I.issue_id = A.issue_id 
INNER JOIN requestors as R on A.issue_id  = R.requestor_id
WHERE A.attachment_status = 1
GROUP BY A.Issue_ID, I.Issue_Name, r.Name
--Specify all columns by name (don't use *)
```

Comment: Your query doesn't work because I need the number of attachments associated with each issue (Issues.Issue_ID).

Comment: @PublicTechie2015 i changed my answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I need the values from the "Requestors" table as well.

Comment: @PublicTechie2015 inner join third table

Comment: I did. The following query produces an error: 'SELECT I.*, A.*, R.*, COUNT(A.attachment_id) AS Count 
FROM Attachments as A 
INNER JOIN Issues I  on I.issue_id = A.issue_id
INNER JOIN Requestors R on R.Issue_ID =  A.Issue_ID 
WHERE A.attachment_status = 1
GROUP BY A.Issue_ID, I.Issue_Name'

Comment: @PublicTechie2015 i changed my answer

Comment: @PublicTechie2015 every column you named in select list must be in group by list except count(columns)

Comment: That worked. I'll accept your answer now. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Keep It Simple and Try This!

```
    SELECT i.Issue_ID, i.Issue_Name, COUNT(a.attachment_id) AS AttachmentCount 
    FROM attachments a JOIN
    issues i  ON 
    i.issue_id = a.issue_id 
    WHERE a.attachment_status = 1
    GROUP BY i.Issue_ID, i.Issue_Name
```

---

Add your **Desired Columns** in Both **Select List** and **Group By Clause** and you are **done**.

Comment: I like your solution because it doesn't use "outer apply", but it doesn't work. What does "s" supposed to reference? I tried tweaking it, but I can't get it to work.